# MongoDB hint doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, mongodb

This is a slightly weird one.
I'm iterating through quite a large database, using a query that checks if certain elements exist. running this query in database without hint takes about 137 seconds, but with hint it goes down to 0 (which is obv preferable). When using it via php

```
$collection->find($params)->hint(array("responses" => 1))->count();
```

and profiling the queries I'm getting this:

> { "ts" : ISODate("2012-05-08T10:11:24.682Z"), "op" : "command", "ns" :
>   "ey_gsat.$cmd", "command" : { "count" : "survey_answers", "query" : {
>   "responses.93" : { "$exists" : true }, "responses.96" : { "$exists" :
>   true }, "responses.99" : { "$exists" : true }, "responses.102" : {
>   "$exists" : true }, "responses.105" : { "$exists" : true },
>   "responses.108" : { "$exists" : true }, "responses.111" : { "$exists"
>   : true }, "responses.114" : { "$exists" : true }, "responses.117" : {
>   "$exists" : true }, "responses.120" : { "$exists" : true },
>   "responses.1" : { "$exists" : true } } }, "ntoreturn" : 1,
>   "responseLength" : 48, "millis" : 137, "client" : "127.0.0.1", "user"
>   : "" }

There is no sign of the query actually using an index when run via php. I have quite a few queries like this running on this site, so the 137 milliseconds all add up, hence the reason why I would like to optimise them. any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: All I can say is ***new technology***

Comment: The PHP driver strips off the hint on purpose, does this work in the shell?

Comment: I double checked all scenarios, and as much as hint seems to speed up the usual find query, whenever I add count to it it ignores the indexes. is that the desired behaviour? is there any way I can utilise the indexes to speed up my calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of count: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2677.  You might want to follow/vote for the issue.  Unfortunately, there's no workaround.  You might want to look into caching the count whenever possible or estimating the total.